# vs code expand selection doesn't respect word separators setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run the command "Expand Selection" with my cursor in a `kebab-case-word-like-this`, I want it to select the whole word including the dashes, but it breaks at the dash, even though my configured "Editor: Word Separators" (`editor.wordSeparators`) does **not** include dash (it's unchanged from the default). Any way to make it select the entire thing on the first expansion? Kebab case is the convention for clojure and this glitch makes it really tedious. It seems that `deleteWordLeft` and `deleteWordRight` also don't respect `editor.wordSeparators`.

Comment: hey sorry I don't know the answer. But have you tried posting this question as an issue on their github repo? I'd guess you might have better luck there.

Comment: I have so far tried stackoverflow, reddit, and the github repo of the selectWord plugin. I may try the main vs code repo but that's a pretty big hammer.

Comment: Dang, sorry man that's frustrating. Good luck!